# How does Netflix submit ratings without a page refresh, and no JavaScript?

Tags: html, http

I'm trying to do something like Netflix's 5 star rating system for my website, and I've noticed that Netflix, even with JavaScript disabled, will still submit ratings without a page refresh. This is apparent because when you manually reload the page, you can see the new rating. However, the change is not visible until you reload the page.

Here's an example of a link on Netflix:

```
<a href="http://movies.netflix.com/SetRating?value=5&pval=4.8&widgetid=M70186045_496624_2_36&authURL=1272123378738.TS7qzDVHSE6abcEeRPuqldimKYc%3C&section=QUEUE" class="rv5" tabindex="0" title='Click to rate the movie "Loved It"'>Rate 5 stars</a>
```

Anybody know how Netflix does this?

Hint: if you look at the source and do a search, you will not find 'iframe' anywhere.
Also, it exhibits this behavior with JavaScript OFF. Otherwise it would update the data and not require a manual refresh. So no AJAX, either. Check it out for yourself, I'm sure many of you have Netflix accounts.

Comment: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: @Jon: "even with JavaScript disabled" -- OP: probably an IFrame you're just not picking up on.

Comment: @BradChristie: I did miss that part, but... how is the iframe going to help? There is no `target` attribute.

Comment: @jon: the anchor could be wrapped in an iframe so a click-refresh doesn't have any affect on the page just the single anchor (and a little real-estate surrounding it). -- think facebook like button.

Comment: I checked the page source, and a ctrl+f doesn't find 'iframe' anywhere.

Comment: @knoell8504: then it's has to be using javascript. there's not too many ways you can skin the cat here; either javascript (ajax) or an iframe.

Comment: @BradChristie: I haven't come across any way in my experience or on the internet to refresh just part of a web page without javascript, even in an iframe. Every time I've tried to reload an iframe, it's just triggered a page refresh. Any other "ways to skin a cat"?

Comment: hmm interesting just tried the iframe idea and it worked. Silly me, I didn't know that was possible. But that still doesn't explain how Netflix does it.

Comment: Why does it matter how Netflix does it? Either you are working on their codebase and have access to their code, documentation and other programmers or you are just trying to solve the problem for your own site and their solution only proves that it is possible.

Comment: I don't want to use iframes; that's what the JavaScript I wrote is for. But I would like to enable partial functionality for those without javascript without complicating it with iframes. Maybe I'm just being stubborn, but that's been the plan all along so I'd rather stick to it if possible.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers, I learned something new about iframes :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a little more research, I found the answer I was looking for. You can do this by sending an HTTP response 204 status code from the page you are sending your request to. For instance, assuming you're sending it to a php script, start the page with this:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Response");
```

As stated here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#32569

> If you haven't used, HTTP Response 204 can be very convenient. 204 tells the server to immediately terminate this request. This is helpful if you want a javascript (or similar) client-side function to execute a server-side function without refreshing or changing the current webpage. Great for updating database, setting global variables, etc.

This is what I'm now using in my scripts.

Comment: +1 just for an interesting find, and, if I could, another +1 for due-diligence. ;-)

Comment: This is an extremely interesting answer for just 2 upvotes. I increased it by 50% for you!