# PHP is not returning me a number type

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point

I tried to follow the instructions in this question: [STAR rating with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css))
but I've just a big problem.

When I do:

```
<span class="stars">1.75</span>
```

or

```
$foo='1.75';
echo '<span class="stars">'.$foo.'</span>
```

**the stars is correctly shown**, but as soon as I do:

```
while($val = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{  
$average =  ($val['services'] + $val['serviceCli']  + $val['interface'] + $val['qualite'] + $val['rapport'] )  / 5 ;

<span class="stars">.$average.</span>
}
```

**the stars stops working**

I double checked the data type in mysql:
they're all `TINYINT(2)`

and I tried this:

```
$average = intval($average);
```

**but it's still not working,**

Comment: try this inside the loop: `var_dump($val);` it should give you the answers you seek

Comment: Maybe the data is not fetched from the DB correctly? Try printing the values in the array $val in the while loop.

Comment: datas are correctly loaded i checked

Comment: Please provide the output of var_dump($val['services'], $average); Put this line at the end of the while loop. Data from a database is usually not converted into the proper php datatype (therefore string). _And_ most importantly, do you print the second last line using echo?

Comment: So what you get when you `var_dump($val);` is something like: `array(5) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=>int(2) [2]=>int(3) [3]=>int(4) [4]=>int(5) }` ?

Comment: var_dump($average) = float(8.36) 
why it isn't working ?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Does it print out <span class="stars">8.36</span>?

Comment: no the HTML looks like : <span style="width: 80px;"></span>
but so does the live example of the script : http://www.ulmanen.fi/stuff/stars.php

Comment: Uhm nope. In the link it looks like: <span class="stars">2.4618164</span>.
Taken from the above code of yours replace <span class="stars">.$average.</span> with echo '<span class="stars">'.$average.'</span>';

Comment: halfdan, i've answered you just below, because it was to hard to read if i would have answered you in here. ;)

Comment: hafdan, i can assure you, on the live demo website, if i go in it with FireBug enabled, i type a value on the input but, then hit, update. The stars is showing, i select the stars wiwh firebug and i have : 
<span style="width: 45px;"></span> // directly copyied from firebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be that the value you have is greater than the 5 allowed in that example.

What you want to do is weight the items such that the total for `$average` is less than or equal to 5.

```
$average = (
    ( $val['services'] / $maxServices )
    + ( $val['serviceCli'] / $maxServiceCli )
    + ( $val['interface'] / $maxInterface )
    + ( $val['qualite'] / $maxQualite )
    + ( $val['rapport'] / $maxRapport )
);
```

The weighting could be even, so each of the values will be less than or equal to 1, or they could have different weights so `services` is worth more than `qualite` (and so on).

Comment: oh my god. i never thought i would be that stupid.
in fact, max stars = 5 , my averages are on 10, so i always have <5 values. *need some sleep*

thanks, sorry to have bother you with THAT kind of stupid problem.

Comment: Well, I thought of that too.. BUT the JavaScript catches this situation and sets all values > 5 to exactly 5. So this shouldn't be the solution to the problem..

Comment: I have a feeling that @halfdan correct, this doesn't solve the problem since your problem was that you were not getting any data back at all...?

Comment: no, in fact, it was entirely my fault, all data that i requested are on 10 (i mean, 8/10 + 9/10 +6 /10 ...  DIVIDE BY 5 gave me all the values.
The stars were all set to 5, that's why i told 'the stars stops working' (i should have precised that they were all set to 5 my bad)

Comment: You should be able to change the css, javascript and double widen the image to make it go to 10 if you want though.

Answer (score 0):

no, `var_dump($val)` gives me ALL the value i get from my big request (text, varchar, int)  [example :

```
array(38) { [0]=>  string(28) "http://www.crystal-serv.com/" 
["siteweb"]=>  string(28) "http://www.crystal-serv.com/" 
[1]=>  string(1) "0" ["offreDedie"]=>  string(100) 
"tick rouge" [2]=>  string(1) "0" ["coupon"]=>
```

..........

Comment: Do you actually need to be retrieving all of the data here?