# How to target a nested strong with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to implement a star rating system using the method here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987545/1543310 I've been able to get it to work successfully but I'm trying to tailor it to the output of the woocommerce star rating system so I can easily change the outputted image.

Basically I'm wondering if there's a way to target and change the contents of the `<strong>` tag in the below html if there wasn't a class attached, as there are a couple other renditions of how the following is outputted, but they all include a strong tag inside a `<div class="star-rating">`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="star-rating">
    <span>
        <strong class="rating">3.5</strong> 
    </span>
</div>
```

I've setup a fiddle here with what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/AwCLm/ with the woocommerce html output included.

Here's a working example I setup, but it requires a class to be set for the `<strong>`: http://jsfiddle.net/YYWQx/1/

Comment: I don't see an id in your second, working example.

Comment: sorry, I meant to write strong, not span in the question. I've edited for clarity. There is a 'rating' class on the strong in the working example.

Comment: Are you trying to "target" the `strong` with jQuery, CSS or both?

Comment: both I guess. I need to apply the css to the strong tag in order to apply the style needed for the stars to display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution I got for you.

Is that what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/migontech/YYWQx/6/

```
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        // Get the value
        var val = parseFloat($(this).html());
        // Make sure that the value is in 0 - 5 range, multiply to get width
        var size = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, val))) * 16;
        // Create stars holder
        var $span = $('<span />').width(size);
        // Replace the numerical value with stars
        $(this).html($span);
    });
}
$(function() {
    $('div.star-rating strong').stars();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited my answer because I have misunderstood the OP.

If you mean you want to target the `<strong>` element regardless of whether it has a `rating` class or not, you can use `$('.star-rating strong').stars();` in your JS, and modify the CSS selectors:

```
.star-rating > span strong {
    display: block;
    background: url(http://testing.wpovernight.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    width: 80px;
    height: 16px;
}   
.star-rating > span strong > strong{
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YYWQx/5/

Comment: I think OP wants to target a strong without having to put the `.rating` class on it. Something like `$(".star-rating strong")` (but that doesn't work).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how that helps. I need to be able to select the `<strong>` regardless of whether or not it has a class associated it. I'm not trying to exclude the rating class, I'm trying to include strongs that have no class.

Answer (score 0):

In you fiddle you have targeting the direct children `>` of the `div.star-rating` which is not going to work instead you shoud try below one:

I think this could help you:

```
 $('div.star-rating strong').stars();
```

because `$('<strong />').width(size);` creates another `<strong>` in the `<strong.rating>`

and the change in the css:

```
strong.rating, strong.rating strong {
  //-----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------You have to include this too.
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I don't see why the selector `div.star-rating strong` doesn't work. If I'm understanding your question, `<div class='star-rating'>` is always present, you just don't know if the nested `<strong>` will have a class or not. In this updated fiddle, the star rating seems to have been updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/AwCLm/6/