# How to Work Jquery Rating Stars Using in Java Application?

Tags: java, jquery, css, rating

In my Java Application have concept of Show Rating Star.

And My java Application giving integer value ex:4, now i'm show the rating Stars four.

So how to do this one into Jquery?

And Display the Star mean we are giving any Image tag other wise write some css to Create Star?

Give me suggestion to create Star and Display java value stars?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is not clear! I hope you are developing a web application using java! I'll give you a concept to send the values to the front end.

write a web service where the front end can use a .GET or an .ajax method to call and get the data.

Get the necessary rating using your code and put it into a hash map with an identifiable key. send the hash map using jSON ( use googles GSON plugin in the java program ).

Catch it using the .AJAX or .GET response and manipulate the id using the hash map key.

Example say your service url is `/getRating`.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/getRating",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(response){
        //Manipulate the response received by the ajax here. (probably change the css according to the value received.)
    }
});
```

Comment: No.. No.. i'm Calling the Java Services and getting the Response back Now if we display the result for example using label tag it will print 4 .. so my intention is printing label Printing Stars on Front end page ... hope Understand..

Comment: Can you post the method how you print the value in the label?

Comment: <c:set var="modalAttributeName" value="MESSAGE_INBOX" />                      
 <c:set var="modalAttribute" value="${requestScope[modalAttributeName]}" />                                 <c:forEach items="${modalAttribute.inboxList}" var="inbox">                <label for="created">${inbox.rating}</label>                                    </c:forEach>

Comment: remove the label tag from the code. Then using the following link design a CSS star. Assign the values using a inline Jscript

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/10-great-css-star-raters/

Sorry here's the link! You would be able to write the CSS using the above link! Read through it!