# getting data from database to 5 stars rating

Tags: jquery, css, rate

I am using this template to display a rating next to a user.

```
{insert name=get_percent value=a assign=mpercent userid=$p.USERID}

  {if $mpercent ne ""}
    <div class='user-rate'>
      rate<span class='green'>{$mpercent}&#37;</span>
    </div>

  {else}
    <div class='user-rate'>not rated yet</div>
  {/if}
```

I'd like to change the rating from a percentage value to a star rating (0-5).

I tried the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css)

this is the code as I added the following CSS:

```
span.stars, span.stars span {
  display: block;
  background:url(../images/stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
  width: 80px;
  height: 16px;
}

span.stars span {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $("span.stars").stars();
});

$.fn.stars = function() {
  return $(this).each(function() {
    $(this).html($('<span />')
      .width(Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, parseFloat($(this).html())))) * 16));
  });
}
```

And have used this for each of the ratings:

```
<p> <span class="stars">{$mpercent}</span>    </p>
```

i used `{$mpercent}` to get the rating of the member, but the result is that I get 5 stars all the time.

If I change the value of span class to a fixed number (let us say 1,2 or 3) I also get the same result.

Comment: I've reformatted your question - if you put the time in to make the question legible, then you'll be much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. The code you have linked explicitly says that you need to make sure the value is between 0 and 5. Using 0-100 therefore will show 5 for 5-100. You need to use `($mpercent/100)*5` to convert to the 0-5 range.
2. You have made the code unnecessarily hard to read by condensing that jQuery plugin to one line.

However, the code looks correct. I suggest you change the value to be between 0 and 5, then double check it's still always showing 5*. Note that this code only runs when the DOM loads, so if you alter the contents of the span using the chrome developer tools or similar you **cannot** expect the star rating to update automatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer
i tried it but it didn't work

the problem is the even if i changed the code {$mpercent} between the <span> to a fixed number like 1, 2 ...etc , i get the same result

Comment: Ok, well - as I said - the code looks right to me. What debugging efforts have you made? You should start by checking the function actually gets called by adding `console.log('stars')` beneath the stars function call.