# Applying jQuery/JavaScript Functions to SQL Data Retrieved by jTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-jtable

I'm more than a bit rusty and I'm having trouble applying the jQuery "star rating" transformation found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css) to data retrieved via MySQL for [jTable](http://www.jtable.org/).

I feel as though I should be using the event handler [`recordsLoaded`](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#event-recordsLoaded) but I cannot find any documentation on how to implement it. Likewise, I think I should be doing a callback or jQuery's `$.when()` to validate the data exists, but every attempt I've made has only resulted in catastrophic failure.

Seeking a rudimentary example on how to apply jQuery/JS functions on data returned through jTable. All assistance welcome.

For example, why wouldn't this work, or what am I messing up with the syntax?

```
$.when(
  $('#data').jtable('load'),
).then(function() {
  $('td.stars').stars();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was:

```
        recordsLoaded: function(event, data) {
          $('td.stars').stars();
        }
```