# How to calculate star rating?

Tags: php, jquery, rating

I have one product and i want to calculate 5 star rating on the basic like and dislike

for example product have

- like = 200 // that means 200 user like that product
- dislike =10 // that means 10 user dislike that particular product

Comment: like/(like + dislike) would get you some percentage... where each 20% would be a complete star...?

Comment: How to calculate star rating on the basis of like count and dislike count ?

Comment: `200/210 = 0.9523` then do `0.9523 * 5 ` and that is your star rating `4.761`.  HOWEVER, it's not accurate info and may be misleading since you don't know if all 200 people who liked before, would have gave 5 stars. Maybe most of them would of only gave 4 if they had the option?

Comment: I wouldn't use a linear percentage * stars mapping. That's hardly weighting in the negative votes or resulting in a representative distribution. (Which you can't unless you have inspected a realistic amount of data points.)

Comment: Amazed at the results found on Google (after spending 30 seconds on it) using "5 star rating php".

Comment: I hate stars. Is shows on a scale of 1 (?!) to 5 (?!) the number of fake reviews plus randomness. No - a score system where upvote adds one and downvote subtracts one is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple PHP function:

```
<?php
    function calculateStarRating($likes, $dislikes){ 
        $maxNumberOfStars = 5; // Define the maximum number of stars possible.
        $totalRating = $likes + $dislikes; // Calculate the total number of ratings.
        $likePercentageStars = ($likes / $totalRating) * $maxNumberOfStars;
        return $likePercentageStars;
    }
?>
```

To call the function:

```
<?php
    $likeCount = 190; 
    $dislikeCount =10; 
    $calculatedRating = calculateStarRating($likeCount, $dislikeCount); 
?>
```

To use the calculated value in Javascript:

```
<script>
    var rating = <?php echo $calculatedRating; ?>;
    alert(rating); // For testing purposes.
</script>
```

These would get you started.

Comment: Also, do have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Below is javascript calculation just to get the idea. You can convert it to whatever language you want.

```
var like = 200;
var dislike = 10
var total = like + dislike ; 

percentOfLikes    = 5 * like / total;
percentOfDislikes = 5 * dislike / total;
console.log(percentOfLikes);
// 4.761904761904762 4.8 stars
console.log(percentOfDislikes);
// 0.23809523809523808 0.2 stars
```