# How can I replace text value to star

Tags: html, css

i'm user query echo rating post as:

```
<a href="link">title</a><div class='rating'>4.5</div>
```

how to change `<div class='rating'>4.5</div>` 
to start image as:

1.5 => star 1.5

3 => start 3.....
by css or anything

Thanks

Comment: What does "user query echo rating post" mean?

Comment: You might find this link helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS and the Unicode character for stars.

Something like this:

```
<span class="rating star1">1</span>
```

With CSS (using generated content - the hex value for a black/full star is `2605`, a white star/outline only is `2606`):

```
.rating.star1:before {
    content: '\2605';
    color: red;
}
```

A basic fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r11vgbwd/

Comment: if is query as `<a href="link">title</a><div class='rating'>4.5</div>` how to echo 4.5 star ? i have add class to `class='rating4.5'` but not css it's

Comment: You want just one star next to the rating? Something like "★4.5" ?