# How to prevent linebreaks between headline and span elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a headline`h2` html element followed by a `span` tag. Both should be shown in a single line.

My purpose is to show text, followed by rating stars. I'm using html+css from [Turn a number into star rating display using jQuery and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css) as follows:

```
<h2 style="display:inline">title
    <span class="stars" style="width:150px">
         <span style="width:100px;"/>
    </span>
</h2>

span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url(stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    height: 16px;
}
span.stars span {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

This works fine, BUT it introduces a linebreak. How can I prevent it?

When I change the following, it would work:

```
span.stars, span.stars span {
       display: inline-block;
}
```

But is this the right way to achieve this? Doesn't `inline-block` cause problems in some browsers?

Comment: try to float the h2 to the left

Comment: remove display:inline from h2 style and remove display:block from span class. There won't be any linebreak.

Comment: display: inline-block; if well used won't cause any problem however... there's still a space between inline-blocks elements. IF you don't want to kind of hack it with many tricks you will find around as adding font-size:0px, margin-left:-1px, etc... floating is the way to go.

Comment: @TashenJazbi but also the image is not shown anymore with this.

Answer (score 1):

just remove display:block from star class. it always introduces a line break like paragraph tage [there is](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

```
<h2 style="display:inline">title
    <span class="stars" style="width:150px">
         <span style="width:100px;"/>
    </span>
</h2>

span.stars, span.stars span {
    background: url(stars.png) 0 -16px repeat-x;
    height: 16px;
}
span.stars span {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the background image anymore with this.

Comment: ok, use background: url(star.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; now your background will be visible

Comment: @membersound also put something between span tag to get background image visible. if you don't want to put anything just write space between that tag. to write a space you've to write &nbsp;

Answer (score -1):

Just use the below CSS. I guess you'll get what you are looking for.

```
<h2>
    <span class="stars" style="width:150px">
         <span style="width:100px;"></span>
    </span>
    title
</h2>

h2{
    position:relative;
}

span.stars{
    background-image: url(http://henty-estate.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/5-stars.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position:relative; 
    display:inline-block; 
    height:16px; 
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `position:absolute;` when you can use `inline-block` or `float`?

Comment: i find this better then inline-block or float. working fiddle to check it - http://jsfiddle.net/zahedkamal87/6jtkku28/

Comment: "My purpose is to show text, followed by rating stars.". yours is just the other way around.

Comment: okay.. i made it with Inline-block as you are trying to achieve it. Here is fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/zahedkamal87/6jtkku28/1/