# how to add rating funtion to particular td in $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to select particular td in table.

```
$.each(result.HotelSearchResult.HotelResults, function (index, item) {
    var imgPath = item.HotelPicture;
    var rate = item.StarRating;
    var table = $('#tableId'); 
    var rows = '<tr><td rowspan="4" width="16.666%"><img src="' + imgPath + '" />'+ "</td>";                                            
    rows += '<tr><td class="code">' + addScore(rate, $("td.code")) + "</td></tr>";                                               
    table.append(rows);
});
```

Here, `addScore` is a function and it requires an element as its second parameter to append stars according to rating. I am following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987524/turn-a-number-into-star-rating-display-using-jquery-and-css), but in my code it is appending all the ratings to particular `td` for each iteration. This means if there are 20 arrays then its appending 20 ratings to each `td` in the table. I want to append one rating per `td`.

This is my table:

```
<div id="divResult5"></div>   
<table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tbody id="tableId" style="border:solid 1px red;"></tbody>
</table>
```

Please tell me how it should be done.

Comment: Can it is possible for you to create a working snippet or fiddle with complete HTML, JS and CSS. It will be easy if we have that.

Comment: `$("td.code")` will return all the `<td>` elements with class "code". That is the reason.

Comment: @vijayP just give me 5 min more, i will provide working fiddle

Comment: that will be really nice @duke...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify addScore as below and try:

```
function addScore(score) {
 var className = 'stars-container stars-'+score.toString();
 return "<span class='"+className+"'>★★★★★</span>";
}
```

And invoke addScore as below:

```
rows += '<tr><td class="code">' + addScore(rate) + '</td></tr>';
```

Here is the reason why the original function is not working:
The original function was expecting a DOM element as second argument, and it appends the score span element to the DOM element.

In your case when you are sending $("td.code") there are two problems associated with it:
The selector "td.code" will select all td-elements whose class is ".code" which means it behaves as below : 
     => when it iterates first row, it will not find any td element because the current td element is not yet in DOM. 
     => when it iterates second row, it will not find current td element but it will find td element of the first row because the first row td-element is also having the same class ".code" 
     => when it iterates nth row, it will not find current td nth element but it will find td elements of the (n-1) rows

So as current td element to which you are trying to append stars is not yet in DOM, you cannot pass that as second argument.

Instead you need a function that will generate HTML markup (span with stars) and you can directly invoke that function, addScore(score) will return the markup.

Comment: no rating showing, only showing undefined @Dhananjaya Kuppu

Comment: @duke I have modified code to return html, please try

Comment: now, it is working fine thnx but i cant understand this function plzz explain me

Comment: @duke I have explained, added some more description in answer.